# How to make use of formula function like "Contains" as case insensitive

Tags: visualforce, contains

I am Comparing a list of two strings in visualforce page using "Contains" function.But currently it retrieves only the exact match.Say,If the Name is **B**urlington it compares the name which contains "**B**urlington" but not "**b**urlington".Is there some other way to check the same?

Page:

```
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!contains(wrap1.acc.Name,wrap2.acc2)}">
```

Comment: Convert All values to upper or lowercase

Comment: @Eric Why didn't you just post that as an answer?

Comment: @AdrianLarson was on mobile at the time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!contains(UPPER(wrap1.acc.Name),UPPER(wrap2.acc2))}">
```

Convert all to upper / lower case

Comment: By the way, @Pri, this is a trick you'll use for the rest of your life in data work (capitalizing or lowercasing both sides of the value comparison) -- so much so that you'll stop even thinking of it as a trick and just think of it as, "how you do a case-insensitive comparison!"  Doesn't even really matter what the tool is.